# Replacing preprocessor-switches by `if constexpr`

Tags: c++, constexpr, preprocessor

I want to get rid of most `#ifdef`-clauses if possible. To that end, my code would contain many cases of the following pattern:

```
template<bool b>
void f(){
    if constexpr (b) {
        invalid;
    }
}
```

to replace code of the form

```
void f(){
    #ifdef FOO
    code_invalid_unless_FOO_is_defined;
    #endif
}
```

The first example not compile, as `invalid_code` is not declared.

I had hoped that everything inside `if constexpr` is ignored, which seems to be not the case. Can I use `if constexpr` at all to eliminate preprocessor usage of that form?

Edit: this question is different from the linked one, because it involves templates. The statements on [this site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) made me think that in that case, the code inside a discarded `constexpr` is not checked.

Comment: if constexpr only works when the condition depends on a template parameter.

Comment: _"...Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. `if constexpr` is __not__ a substitute for the `#if` preprocessing directive:..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if

Comment: It's summarised pretty succinctly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46512580/817643).

Comment: If "everything" inside `if constexpr` was ignored, how would the compiler determine where the `if constexpr` ends?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the style of the second code snippet. Why do you want to rewrite it? (Note that I'm asking an engineering question; "ugh, preprocessor bad" is not an engineering answer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#if Vs if constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797365/if-vs-if-constexpr)

Comment: @RichardCritten That's a good hint. However, it also does not work in templates, as the updated question shows.

Comment: It's not like you can opt of of preprocessor completely, what with RTL headers being what they are.